# How to show UIAlertView of one view controller class from AppDelegate and to hit clicked button at index method if alert button clicked?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

I am calling a view controller method which displays UIAlertview, and alertview is displaying but clicked button at index method is not calling. How to fix it?

Following code had used in TestViewController class

```
- (void) test
{
    UIAlertView *alert1 = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"OPTUM" message:NSSAlertMessage delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"NO" otherButtonTitles:@"YES", nil];
            alert1.tag = 3;
            [alert1 show];
}
```

And calling the above method from app delegate like,

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{

    NSLog(@"Notification Received: %@", userInfo);
    NSString *NSSMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", userInfo];
    UIStoryboard *storyboard=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        TestViewController *obj1=[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"View Controller"];
        [obj1 handleNotificationMessage: NSSMessage];
}
```

Thanks in Advance, for any help.

Comment: in wich class are you implementing the clickedButtonAtIndex?

Comment: Clicked button at index is at TestVIewController class but now moved to App Delegate. Its working now. Thanks a lot for response

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your calling view controller is declared as a UIAlertViewDelegate:

```
@interface TestViewController : UIViewController<UIAlertViewDelegate>
```

And make sure `clickedButtonAtIndex` has the correct signature:

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

Comment: Yes already delegate given and clickedButtonAtIndex had also given